# $form_state['redirect'] disables saving node

Tags: 7, redirection, entities

I'm having a node form in tabs using field_groups. I can access a tab directly by going to the url node/{nodeid}/edit#some_id_in_that_tab.

I want to make a button that submits the form and goes to the next tab. So I added a submit button to the form:

```
 $form['actions']['nexttab'] = Array (
                   "#type" => "submit",
                   "#value" => "nexttab",
                   "#weight" => 10,
                   "#submit" => Array ("dzh_2012_form_nexttab")
                    );
```

In the function dzh_2012_form_nexttab I've put:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = the_url_described_above
```

When I click this nexttab button I get redirected to the right tab but the form isn't saving.

If I add:

```
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
```

The form is saved but the redirect isn't working anymore.

Any idea to have both: save the form and redirect it?

Thanks in advance for your answer/effort.

--
Willem

Comment: It may be the problem of missing ","  in   "#submit" => Array ("dzh_2012_form_nexttab"),.

Comment: Well. i guess that's just difference in coding. I normally build in C# and that would give a compile error. I never end arrays with a komma and until now php accepted both. I'll give it a try

Comment: as expected, no change...